# `Invalid object name` unless I specify database name in SQL Server 2008 queries

Tags: sql-server

Up until today I've been able to run queries without using the `[databaseName].[dbo].[fieldName]` syntax. And all of a sudden, if I use `select * from myTable` I get an error for an `invalid object`.  I can't possibly think of something that happened between shutting down my PC yesterday and today.  Anyone know anything about this?

```
Msg 208, Level, 16, State 1 Line 1
Invalid object name 'mytable'
```

It's only been since today that I have to include the database name in the query.  There are no other connections open and no other users of this instance of SQL Server.

Comment: post the actual query and actual error you are getting, so that we can help you.

Comment: you are using the databaseName,right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean a query of the form `select [fieldName] from [databaseName].[dbo].[mytable]`

Here are some possible things to look out for:

- Make sure that you are in the correct database context / catalogue (i.e. `use [databasename]`, or select the correct database from the `Available Databases` drop down in SSMS)

[image]

- Ensure that if you have a case sensitive collation on your database that the object names in your query match the exact case.
- Check that the default schema for your user hasn't changed on this database. Although the default schema is usually `[dbo]`, it can be changed.

**Edit : More ideas:**

- Do `SELECT  DB_NAME()` to see what the current database name is.
- Check to see if someone has dropped the table or view entirely, e.g. from the target database, run:

```
Select * from sysobjects where name = 'myobject' 
OR
Select * from sys.tables where name = 'mytable' 
OR
Select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

Comment: the schema hasn't changed, and case sensitivity hasn't changed.  I'm not sure what exactly you mean with the database context/catalogue.

Comment: I have a crappy touch pad on my laptop and I was using the wrong database.  To the direct left of the execute button for running queries, where it has a list of the databases on your SQL Server, what's that thing called?  That's where my problem was.  Thanks :)